# Transform JSONArray values in WSO2 EI

Tags: arrays, json, transformation, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am having some **transformation logic during mediation** in wso2 EI. i have stuck while *"@type":"Lead" into "attributes":{"type":"Lead"}* transformation.

**Note:** i know to use payloadfactory to achieve this( Expected format). received at least 1000 JSONObject under getFields Array.

**Input:**

```
{
"getDataResponse":{
    "result":{
        "DataSyncTime":"sometime",
        "getFields":[
            {
                "@type":"Lead",
                "FirstName":"Justin"
            },
            {
                "@type":"Lead",
                "FirstName":"Manoj"
            }
          //received atleast 1000 records ie jsonobject here(Dynamic)
            ],
            "Message" :"Text messsage",
            "Success":200
    }
}
```

}

**Expected:**

```
{
    "DataSyncTime":"sometime",
    "getEvents":[],
    "getFields":[
            {
                "attributes":{"type":"Lead"},
                "FirstName":"Justin"
            },
            {
                "attributes":{"type":"Lead"},
                "FirstName":"Manoj"
            }

            ],
            "getTask":[],
            "Message" :"Text messsage",
            "Success":200
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do a XML to JSON transformation here?

Comment: Hi @ArunanSugunakumar,
Thanks for reply. we already did transformation using messsageType as application/json from xml payload, after that this json format conversion. Let me know if you need any other info.

Answer (score 0):

Trying using Foreach mediator with Payload Factory mediator to loop through the array. If Payload Factory does not satisfy your requirement, you may have to use a Custom Class mediator to achieve your requirement.